# Customize Jira server Release Note

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, jira-plugin

Is it  possible to customize Jira Server Release Note to display the files that have been modified and users that made the modification ?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. You can write a Java add-on/app/plugin to do this. Or you can use REST to retrieve each issue in a saved filter and generate the HTML yourself.

Comment: Do you have any useful links for that purpose ?

Comment: Sorry, nothing I can share.